# Equivalent function of Matlab's filter2 in OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I need to convert the following matlab code into OpenCV and obtain exactly the same result.

In matlab:

```
A = [1 2 3];
f = [4 5 6];
result = filter2(f, A);
```

This gives out as:

```
result = [17    32    23]
```

In OpenCV, I tried these lines:

```
cv::Mat A = (cv::Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 1, 2, 3);
cv::Mat f = (cv::Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 4, 5, 6);
cv::Mat result;
cv::filter2D(A, result, -1, f, cv::Point(-1, -1), 0, cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
```

This gives me:

```
result = [21 32 41]
```

How can I obtain the same result as of Matlab?? I doubt the anchor point in OpenCV causes this difference, but I cannot figure out how to change it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `ddepth` parameter you have kept as -1 i.e. same as src, have you tried changing to `CV_64F`?

Comment: I tried, but it gives me error saying 'unsupported combination of source format (=5) and destination format (=6) ... '.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `cv::BORDER_CONSTANT`, which pads the array with zero rather than duplicating the neighboring element:

```
cv::filter2D(A, result, -1, f, cv::Point(-1, -1), 0, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT);
```

Result is:

```
result = [17, 32, 23]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to post.  +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks, I wish I could come up with some documentation to back up this observation, but it is seriously lacking on both the Matlab and OpenCV side. :(

Comment: For MATLAB, it *kind of* implies that the borders are zero-filled: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html.  If you look at the `valid` flag, it tells you that it does zero-pad the borders, but it doesn't actually tell you that it's doing it outside of the `valid` flag.  My guess is it actually is regardless of what flag you use, and depending on the flag, some elements are discarded.  Zero-padding is still done though.  For OpenCV: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d - It tells you that the default is `BORDER_DEFAULT`, which does do zero-padding.

Comment: @rayryeng I see what you mean about the `valid` flag for Matlab, but if I use `BORDER_DEFAULT` I get `[25, 32, 35]` which would  mean it's getting padded with `2` for some reason? The only place that I could find that states `BORDER_CONSTANT` pads with zero was in the tutorial here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/copyMakeBorder/copyMakeBorder.html

Comment: Oops... I thought `BORDER_DEFAULT` does zero-padding.  yikes.  I hate OpenCV documentation because it's inconsistent, and it makes you jump over hoops just to figure out what one flag means!... and even then it's not reliable!

Comment: btw, after trying 'cv::BORDER_CONSTANT', the result is in reverse order, as [23 32 17].

Comment: @E_learner Interesting. I used the exact code from your question and only changed to `cv::BORDER_CONSTANT` and just confirmed that I get the answer in the proper order, `[17 32 23]`. One thing that might cause the reverse order is if you reverse the array and filter. Can you double-check your code?

Comment: Just realized my comment might be a bit unclear. When I say reverse, I mean reverse the order of `A` and `f` in the argument list like `cv::filter2d(f, ..., A, ...)` rather than what I've used which is `cv::filter2d(A, ..., f, ...)`.

Comment: @beaker: yes, you're right. Now it gives me exactly the same result :) Thank you.