# Equivalent of Matlab filter2(filter, image, 'valid') in python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I want to know what will be the equivalent of Matlab's `filter2(filter, image, 'valid')` function in python OpenCV or scikit-image library. I am mainly concerned with the `valid` argument which allows to calculate the convolution of filter and image without zero padding the image. I am aware of the fact that [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212944/equivalent-function-of-matlabs-filter2-in-opencv) is posted on this forum but the equivalent of `filter2` function with `valid` argument has not been described properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html) for `filter2` says that `filter2(H, X, shape)` is equivalent to `conv2(X,rot90(H,2),shape)`;

A [python equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121269/2d-convolution-in-python-similar-to-matlabs-conv2) to `conv2` is `signal.convolve2d`. So the equivalent you're looking for is:

```
signal.convolve2d(X, np.rot90(H), mode='valid')
```

Comment: Also see `scipy.ndimage.convolve`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought `ndimage.convolve` always did the equivalent of matlab's `filter2` with the option `'same'`, and the OP has asked specifically about the `'valid'` option.

Comment: I guess my thinking was that the OP could then do padding of various sorts easily, but you're right.

Comment: I think it should be signal.convolve2d(X, np.rot90(H, k=2), mode='valid') otherwise the default is k=1 and you are rotating the array 90 degrees

Answer (score 3):

In matlab

```
a=[[1, 2, 0, 0];[5, 3, 0, 4];[0, 0, 0, 7]; [9, 3, 0, 0]];
k=[[1,1,1];[1,1,0];[1,0,0]];
a_k=filter2(k, a, 'valid')
ak=conv2(a,rot90(k,2), 'valid')
```

> > a_k =

```
11     5
17    10
```

> > ak =

```
11     5
17    10
```

In python

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 0, 0],[5, 3, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 7], [9, 3, 0, 0]])
k = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,0]])
from scipy import signal
print(signal.convolve2d(a, np.rot90(k,2), mode='valid'))
```

> > [[11  5]
> >      [17 10]]